# Google VM - Command not found | SOLVED

Tags: google-compute-engine

I had my VM stopped for about a month. After restarting it today I can't run any command in the shell. I reset the instance through the reset button and also upgraded the instance but nothing seems to work.

Google doesn't seem to have an option to submit a support ticket and it redirected me here to create a question instead.

[image]

Hopefully, someone can help me with this.

Update: below command helped me. Looks like GO that I had installed replaced previous PATH settings

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: Posting this as an answer and then accepting it will let people (and the search algorithms) know that this has a fix.

Comment: @Damodar, please post this as an answer because this would be very helpful to the community, especially those who will encounter similar case as yours.

Comment: Done. Thank you RobertG & sysadmin1138.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below command helped me. Looks like the GO that I had installed replaced previous PATH settings.

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Then, I checked ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_aliases and replaced PATH added by GO with the above export PATH line.